# How can I merge Cities and Countries

Tags: php, mysql, json

I downloaded a database table with almost all countries and cities in the world.

The table is displayed like that:

> location_id -> Name -> location_type -> parent_id

location_type is the type of location, 0 is equal to country, 1 is equal to city.

parent_id is the id from the country when the location is a city.

And I would like to display the data for the users like that:

City, country name.

```
Ex: Lisbon, Portugal
```

And print using Json

Can you guys help me building this Query?

My Query:

```
$locations = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name, location_id, parent_id FROM location WHERE location_type = 1 ");
$locarray = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($locations))
    {
    $locarray[] = $row;
    }
```

As you can see, I'm only displaying the cities, I would like to get the parent_id from the city, and print the name from the country where this city is situated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add table structures also?

Comment: Your table is excessive, if record has parent_id it's a city, location type is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT c2.name,c1.name, c1.location_id, c1.parent_id
FROM 
location c1 join location c2 on c1.`parent_id`=c2.`location_id` 
WHERE c1.location_type = 1
```